# Bloquear inscrições além do valor estipulado em formulário PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if, tabela-html

Tenho um sistema de administração de cursos onde o professor cadastra uma turma e o aluno acessa uma página com uma tabela com todas as turmas e se inscreve na que achar melhor.

O problema é que muitos alunos estão se cadastrando numa turma que deveria comportar bem menos, então, o que eu queria fazer:

O professor estipula a quantidade de alunos que podem participar, aí na hora que um aluno fizer a sua inscrição naquela turma, compara a quantidade de alunos permitidos pelo professor com a quantidade de alunos já cadastrados, se ainda tem vaga, a inscrição é salva, se não, aparece um alert e volta pra página anterior.

Essa é a página que o aluno acessa com a tabela que mostra as turmas existentes:

```
<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_qualquer') or die(mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_query("select * from turmas");

//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysql_field_name($qry,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }


    $table .= '<td><form action="inscricao.php" method="post">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOME" value="' . $r["NOME"] . '">';
    $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> Inscreva-se</i></button>'; 
    $table .= '</form></td>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

Essa é a página de inscrição que aparece quando o aluno clica no botão para se inscrever:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1 style="
                margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
            <p> </p>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateP.php" style="
                    text-align: left;
                    margin-top:50px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?php echo $formacao; ?>">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA" value="<?php echo $turma; ?>">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="COLABORADOR">Colaborador: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR">
                                <option>Selecione...</option>
                                <?php while($colab = mysqli_fetch_array($queryColaboradores)) { ?> 
                                <option value="<?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?>"><?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="AREA">Área: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="AREA" name="AREA">
                                <option> MITV </option>
                                <option> CTCA </option>
                                <option> VSPA </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="DATA">Data: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="DATA" name="MES">
                                <option> jan </option>
                                <option> fev </option>
                                <option> mar </option>
                                <option> abr </option>
                                <option> mai </option>
                                <option> jun </option>
                                <option> jul </option>
                                <option> ago </option>
                                <option> set </option>
                                <option> out </option>
                                <option> nov </option>
                                <option> dez </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="PREVISTO">Status: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" value="Previsto">
                         </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline disabled">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="REALIZADO" id="REALIZADO" value="Realizado" disabled> Realizado
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"> Salvar </i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                            <strong>Hey! </strong> Antes de realizar o cadastro, certifique-se de que não se esqueceu de nada! :)
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                            //ESSE É O TESTE QUE EU TENHO FEITO E QUE NÃO TEM FUNCIONADO 

                            $limite = "SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE ID = 'TURMA' and NOME = 'FORMACAO'";

                            $contador = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS ComparaLIMITE FROM participantes WHERE TURMA = 'turma' and FORMACAO = 'formacao'";
                            if ($contador <= $limite) { header("Location: inscricao.php"); } 
                            else { 
                                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                        alert("Essa turma estava completa");
                                        window.history.go(-1);
                                    </script>';
                             }

                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O que eu fiz até agora foi adicionar uma coluna a mais na minha tabela do banco de dados e um campo no formulário do professor pra ele estipular a quantidade de alunos, o name do campo é LIMITE.

O que eu quero fazer é comparar o limite com a quantidade de escritos nessa página com o formulário de inscrição e o cadastro só ser validado caso o limite seja menor que a quantidade de inscritos.

Como eu faço pra fazer essa comparação de número de alunos já inscritos naquela turma com a quantidade estipulada pelo professor quando clicar no botão?

Comment: Como você armazena a inscrição de cada aluno no curso?

Comment: Quando o aluno clica pra se inscrever abre um formulário que já vem escrito a turma e o id da turma pra ele colocar as informações dele. Eu salvo esse formulário numa tabela chamada "participantes"

Comment: Então basta contar quantos registros já há na tabela "participantes" para o determinado curso e comparar com a coluna "limite".

Comment: Sim, mas como eu faço isso dentro do botão pra ele saber pra onde ele redireciona?

Comment: Dentro do botão não. Você pode fazer isso na página que realiza a inscrição do aluno, só permitindo finalizar quando houver vagas, caso contrário redireciona o usuário.

Comment: NOSSA, BOA IDEIA! Vou fazer isso, obrigada.